# Angular 9 issues with MSAL library

Tags: angular, angular8, azure-ad-msal, angular9

I am having issues with MSAL library in angular 9

```
No redirect callbacks have been set. Please call handleRedirectCallback() with the appropriate function
```

I do have handleRedirectCallback() in my authentication service class

```
 private authService: MsalService,
 this.authService.handleRedirectCallback((authError, response) => {
        //do stuff
        }

        //do stuff
      });
```

But this seems to be not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of the library did you use? 
Did you use the .js-library or its angular wrapper?

Comment: @WorksLikeACharm 1.2.2-beta.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using angular, it might be a good idea to use the [msal-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular) library. It worked for me in an angular 9 project, but I had to manually update the "msal" library in package.json to "^1.3.0-beta.0".

Answer (score 2):

Please see this & you can modify your code accordingly. This thread is from msal-angular but you can do it's equivalent stuff if you are using the js library as well.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/angular8-sample-app/src/app/app.component.ts

The issue was tracked at (see the last comment)
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1184